# jQuery Validation plugin: How to force a certain phone number format ###-###-####

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have jQuery Validation plugin on a page. When someone types the phone number into the form field, I want the validator to only recognize a certain format:

```
###-###-####
```

I see this in the JavaScript:

```
phone_number: {
    required: true,
    number: true 
},
```

Can I add something there to specify the required format for the phone number? I found something about adding the [jQuery Mask plugin](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/phone-number-validation-in-jquery), but if I can avoid it, I'd rather not add to the page weight. (Plus...surely there must exist some way to validate only a certain format.)

Comment: There's already a rule for this called `phoneUS`.  It's not for that exact strict format because it also allows `()` and dashes optional, but it only accepts US phone numbers.

Comment: We really want only that exact format, so that when the data routes into the CRMs it's formatted the way we want it to display.

Comment: I’d strongly urge you to refrain from doing this: On the client-side, it’s best to be flexible with the format you allow. Your CRM requirement is a very weak argument for not doing so: You can still easily transform the given phone number into the desired format on the server-side before passing it on to the CRM. Remember: computers are good at finding patterns in input but humans are most comfortable if they can enter their information in a way they’re used to.

Comment: Thank you for your input. For a future redesign (coming in abt 6 months) this is something on the plate. But I'm routing this form data into multiple different CRMs, all of which I am learning as-I-go. I have requests from the users of all these CRMs to have the phone numbers formatted a certain way. This is in addition to everything else that I have to do. Best-practices wise, formatting in the CRM is the smartest method. Time-prioritization-for-this-month wise, forcing formatting on the front end is the way I'm going for now.

Comment: Ok. Just remember that people who don’t have JavaScript enabled will be able to input any value so there’s some validation you’ll have to do server-side either way…

Comment: Yes, that's another thing I've told them. They're in triage mode at this point, and as much as it's making my teeth itch, I can't always get the go-ahead for the best-practice solution on this one particular site. (The process we're going through for another site is very reassuring. Building smart and scalable from the get-go. We'll be doing the same thing to this particular headache-of-a-site in half a year.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[@Sparky's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15482615/497356) is good if you are a little flexible, but just in case you want *just* that format, you can add a custom rule:

```
$.validator.addMethod('customphone', function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/.test(value);
}, "Please enter a valid phone number");

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myform").validate({
        rules: {
            field1: 'customphone'
        }
    });
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kqczf/16/

You can easily make this into a custom class rule. This way you could just add a class to each input that you want to have the rule and possibly omit the rules object from the `validate` call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myform").validate();
});

<input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" class="required customphone" />
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kqczf/17/

Comment: Thanks @Andrew - that looks like what I'm trying to do. Do I add that into the document header, and just make sure that it calls out the proper form ID? (And for cases where this is a global include, and I want to add this action to a few different form IDs, can I have multiple form IDs? And for the field1 - does that need to match the field's class name, or id, or both?)

Comment: You could use a class rule, I'll update my answer. If you do it for each form, the rule key (`field1`) needs to match up with the field *name*. Sounds like using a class rule is what you want though, I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Leigh: You can put the `$.validator.addMethod` and $.validator.addClassRules` lines in your document header. Your call to `.validate` should occur when the document is ready.

Comment: You do not need the `addClassRules` method to simply use this custom rule within `class`.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/kqczf/18/

Comment: @Sparky: Thanks for the tip, I didn't realize it would work without it.

Comment: You'd need the `addClassRules` method if you wanted to assign a "compound" rule to a class name:  http://jsfiddle.net/kqczf/19/

Answer (score 6):

Simply use the `phoneUS` rule included in the [jQuery Validate plugin's `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/additional-methods.js).

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/c9zy9/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            phone_number: {
                required: true,
                phoneUS: true
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Alternatively, instead of including the entire `additional-methods.js` file, you can just pull out the `phoneUS` method.

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/dSz5j/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneUS", function (phone_number, element) {
        phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, "");
        return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 && phone_number.match(/^(\+?1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/);
    }, "Please specify a valid phone number");

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            phone_number: {
                required: true,
                phoneUS: true
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what the user wants--the dashes are optional and +1 is also allowed.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker, I appreciate that but sometimes the user doesn't even know these rules already exist.

Comment: In this case, I wasn't aware that the rule existed, so that you for that. But we do need it to be that very exact format; and for our current purposes, they're telling me that they don't care about non-US phone numbers. (Which I think is going to bite them in the backside, but...there ya go. They've heard my objections, they've given their decision.)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the jQuery [Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/).  It allows you to mask the input with something like this:

```
$("#phone_number").mask("999-999-9999");
```

Comment: Thank you; but I'd like to try and accomplish this without adding any additional plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this, and it works well as per your requirement

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      phoneUS: true
    }
  }
});
```